# How do i keep track of correct answers?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner Keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String firstname =Keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome "+ firstname+  "!"+ " Please answer the following questions:");
    int x =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int y =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;

    int sum = (x+y);
    System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = ");
    String sInput = Keyboard.nextLine();
    int answer1 = Integer.parseInt(sInput);
    if (answer1 ==sum){
        System.out.println("Correct!");
    }else{
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
    }
    System.out.println("The correct answer is " +sum);
```

I have no clue on how to keep track of the correct answers. I need something to keep track of when it prints correct. I don't know what to do though. I know I just need to record the corrects and divide by four. Four because thats how many questions I have in my quiz.

Comment: You need a *data structure* to keep track of information, such as an array or a List.

Comment: I know, but i don't know how that would look and how i would put that with each of the other questions

Comment: A good programmer must learn to do their own research before asking for help :)

Comment: How do you keep track of correct answers? Just look a bit further below. Check back at regular intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to keep track of how many right answers were provided, just add an int variable starting with 0 as a value and increment it. If you want to keep track of the questions and answers which were right, create an empty ArrayList and add a string every time a correct answer is provided.

Here an example of the second option:

```
    ArrayList<String> correctAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String firstname =keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome "+ firstname+  "!"+ " Please answer the following questions:");
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
        int x =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int y =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;

        int sum = (x+y);
        System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = ");
        String sInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        int answer1 = Integer.parseInt(sInput);
        if (answer1 ==sum){
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            correctAnswers.add(x + " + " + y + " = " + sum);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
            System.out.println("The correct answer is " +sum);     
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Correct answers:");
    for (String correctAnswer : correctAnswers) {
        System.out.println(correctAnswer);
    }
```

It asks 10 questions, keeps track of the right answers and outputs them after the 10th question.

An example for the first option:

```
    int correctAnswers=0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your name: ");
    String firstname =keyboard.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Welcome "+ firstname+  "!"+ " Please answer the following questions:");
    int totalAnswers=4;
    for (int i=0;i<totalAnswers;i++) {
        int x =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
        int y =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;

        int sum = (x+y);
        System.out.println(x + " + " + y + " = ");
        String sInput = keyboard.nextLine();
        int answer1 = Integer.parseInt(sInput);
        if (answer1 ==sum){
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            correctAnswers++;
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Wrong!");
            System.out.println("The correct answer is " +sum);     
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Correct answers: "+ correctAnswers + "("+correctAnswers*100/totalAnswers+"%)");
```

Comment: can you show what that would look like? when i add a string what do i put with it? i can't put 1 because i don't know if the user will input the correct answer

Comment: I see the 10 you put in, so for mine i would change to 4 correct? I have 4 questions total

Comment: Yes, either import java.util.* (for Scanner and ArrayList) or import java.util.ArrayList additionally to java.util.Scanner.

Comment: Also note that the variable Keyboard should be called keyboard (first letter should be small).

Comment: I followed your template and when i print the correct answers it just prints the question. e.g. [20+14=34] not how many i got correct

Comment: It prints both the question and the answer e.g. 3 + 7 = 10

Comment: i don't want it to do that. I need it to say you got 1 correct answer, that is a 25%

Comment: It'd been quicker if you had added this precision to the question. see my edited answer

Comment: i am getting errors saying it can't convert Arraylist<String> to int. The error is on (correctAnswers++;) and System.out.println("Correct answers: "+ correctAnswers + "("+(correctAnswers)*100/totalAnswers+"%)");

Comment: Please read the first line of the code in my answer. Do you use that or do you still use the first line of my previous answer ?

Comment: i had both put in. Which one should i have in?

Comment: I got it to remember the correct answers.THANKS! How do i get it to run the quiz just once? Once its complete its starts again. I just want a one time deal.

Comment: Please only use the second code. If you start mixing both it will never work.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. With my code it asks 4 questions and ends after writing the number of correct answers

Comment: Nevermind i fixed the issue!! Thanks again man! You are best!!

Comment: Is there anyway to like give you a good rating for helping? I am new to this site

Comment: Accepting the answer is fine.